# How to configure pyinstaller spec for Python _modules_ (those started as `python -m module_name`) instead of a script

Tags: pyinstaller, python-module

I had to turn my Python script to a module (to avoid the *ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package* error in pytest).

I start my server in Docker and elsewhere using the `python -m server.server --other-arguments` command.

I am trying to package the same code using Pyinstaller (but would happily use any other tool), but cannot figure out how to convince Pyinstaller to start my script as a module.

I package using this syntax:

```bash
pyinstaller --onefile server/app.py --name "My-app-name" --python-option "--other-arguments"
```

But that starts the script as `python server/app.py ...` which subsequently fails with the *ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package* error.
The `--python-option` takes just one argument and according to the documentation it really only support Python verbosity or what.

How can I specify that the .exe should start my script using the `python -m server.app --other-args` syntax? Or what tool should I use?

Comment: I have same question. Do you get any solution for this?

Comment: No, I did not. And I dropped the approach : [